# Husky Hook does not work properly with Test

Tags: husky, git-husky

I'm configuring `Husky` to block `commits` if the `prettier` or `eslint` accuses both an `error` or `warn`, and block the `push` if it doesn't pass the `tests`.

However, when running the `test`, the `test` `CLI` is displayed **(it is in the image below)**, with this, no key works, but I can only finish by clicking with the shortcut `ctrl+z`, **which** **suspends my** `push`.

**MY CODE IN** `.HUSKY` **FOLDER:**

**pre-commit**

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

yarn prettier-check
yarn lint-check
```

**pre-push**

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

yarn test
```

**MY** `PACKAGE.JSON`:

```
{
    "name": "web-whatsapp",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "prettier-check": "prettier --check 'src/**/*.{ts,tsx}'",
        "prettier-fix": "prettier --write 'src/**/*.{ts,tsx}'",
        "lint-check": "eslint 'src/**/*.{ts,tsx}'",
        "lint-fix": "eslint --fix 'src/**/*.{ts,tsx}'",
        "prepare": "husky install"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
        "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
        "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
        "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
        "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
        "styled-components": "^5.2.3",
        "typescript": "^4.1.2",
        "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.22.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.22.0",
        "eslint": "^7.24.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.2.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
        "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.3.5",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.23.2",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
        "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^4.0.1",
        "husky": "^6.0.0",
        "lint-staged": "^10.5.4",
        "prettier": "^2.2.1"
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    }
}
```

[image: Problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what I had to do was this ..

1. Install the `cross-env` library in **development mode**. This library causes the terminal to clear the buffer at the end of the test run in order to continue with the `pre-push` Hook.
2. I inserted the following in the `"test"` scripts:

   `"test": "cross-env CI = true react-scripts test --passWithNoTests"`

**About `CI = true`**

This environment variable, short for **Continuous Integration**, is commonly defined in various `CI` environments, such as **Travis CI** and **Github Actions**, among many others.

**NOTE**

**Do not use the** `--watchAll` **flag, as it will "lock" the terminal.**